# Disable row selection and just allow checkbox to be selected in Mutliselect of PrimeNG

Tags: javascript, angular, primeng

I am working on a requirement in which i am using PrimeNG multiselect. This multiselect has a checkboxes which are followed by texts in it. I want to disable the row selection and only allow checkboxes to be selected of these rows. Below is the example:
Scenerio explained with screenshot:

If i click on text "*1 text*", "*2 text*", etc the values are selected but i want to disable this selection and only allow checkbox to be selected.

Here is the stackblitz example for reference: [Stackblitz Demo click here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-multiselect-placeholder-fjjup5?file=src/app/app.component.ts).

[image]

Following Code which i used in my component html:
`<p-multiSelect [options]="items" defaultLabel="Select items" [showHeader]="false" </p-multiSelect>`

Code for items in array used in dropdown:

```
items: SelectItem[] = [
  { value: 1, label: '1 text' },
  { value: 2, label: '2 text ' },
  { value: 3, label: '3 text' },
 ];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this [Stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/customize-multiselect?file=src/app/app.component.html)

---

**SOLUTION 1:**
As this selection is default behavior of primeNg multiSelect so with `onChange` event Emitter of p-multiSelect I am removing the added value or adding the removed value on deselect value.

**SOLUTION 2:**
Using `event.stopPropagation()` but this works only if I click label but clicking row still select/deselect value.

Comment: Thank you for the solution provided, I must say it was very descriptive and worked out well in my case. I need extended support for my requirement it will be helpful if you can help me out into this,  following scenario : i have a icon for each value in multiselelct when i click on it it displays a popup, the problem is when i click ok of the popup the dropdown of multiselect closes, i dont waana close it , is there any way to figure out the solution , stackblitz example created : [click here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/customize-multiselect-withpopup?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Added [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/customize-multiselect-withpopup-ztbvcv?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: you are a Rockstar !! your solutions are perfect, thank you so much for precious time and helping me out, i have raised another question to solve this, if you can answer the same there i can give you upvote there as well. Link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65284562/disable-dropdown-close-of-multiselect-on-click-of-a-field-inside-multiselect-dro