# Disable dropdown close of multiselect on click of a field inside multiselect dropdown in PrimeNG

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

I am working on a requirement in which I am using PrimeNG multiselect. This multiselect has checkboxes followed by some text and logo. On click of logo I am displaying some data in popup. On click of the ok button of popup the background multiselect closes, where in I need to disable closing of popup on click of logo.
Heere is the stackblitz example for reference: [Stackblitz Demo click here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/customize-multiselect-withpopup-ic8wxh?file=src/app/app.component.html).

**Step 1: Open mutiselect and click on logo**

[image: Step 1: open mutiselect and click on logo]

**Step 2: Click ok of popup**

[image]

**Step 3:  Multiselect Dropdwon closes**

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/customize-multiselect-withpopup-ztbvcv?file=src/app/app.component.ts) Solution.

---

Achieved this using `onPanelHide` eventEmitter which calls **checkState** there I am keeping panel opened with 
 `this.multiInput.show();` 
If popup is opened.

Comment: Wasn't aware of onPanelHide eventEmitter, thanks for the ssupport provided, great work Cheers!

Comment: when I am trying to achieve the same using angular formly using viewchild for multiselect it is failing, it will be helpful if you can help me out in this , link of rework :  https://stackblitz.com/edit/modal-issue-this-wasnt-defined-well-gzwa48?file=app/app.component.ts

Comment: Check this https://stackblitz.com/edit/modal-issue-this-wasnt-defined-well-pumv83?file=app/formly-field-primeng-multiselect.ts

Answer (score 2):

I found a much shorter solution that worked in my application. I had an issue where clicking the checkbox would allow the multi-select to disappear/close. The multi-select should stay open until the user clicks outside or presses the drop-down arrow.

HTML:

```
    <p-multiSelect #multiInput
      styleClass="pMultiSelectMaxWidth"
      (onChange)="
      keepMultiSelectOpen()"
    ></p-multiSelect>
```

TS:

```
  keepMultiSelectOpen() {
    this.multiInput.show();
    event.stopPropagation();
  }
```