# Bootstrap Modal popup component not working on click of angular formly element

Tags: javascript, angular, ngx-formly

I have a reuquirement in which i am using a multiselect of angular formly  which also has logo for each row. **On click of this logo i want to load modal popup component**, i am following a Stackblitz Demo for calling modal-component in app.component on click of element.

The link of demo which i followed :   [Bootstrap modal Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-modal-x1stln?file=src/app/app.module.ts)

My workaround demo which i am implenenting is as follows : [Workaround Demo Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-formly-ui-primeng-pgtbb5?file=app/app.component.ts)

The error which i am getting on click of logo with the function **openModal()** is of undefined object.

[image]

How to i rectify this while working with angular formly?

Following is the snippet of the code:

**multiselect formly component**

```
@Component({
selector: 'formly-field-multiselect',
template: `<br><p-multiSelect  [options]="to.options"
  [formControl]="formControl"
  [formlyAttributes]="field"
  [showClear]="!to.required" >
  <ng-template let-item pTemplate="item">
  <div>{{item.label}}</div>
   <div>
   <i class="pi pi-check" (click)="to.openModal()"></i>
   </div>
  </ng-template>
</p-multiSelect>
`,
})
```

**app.component.ts** in which modal component(calenderComponent) is called

```
fields: FormlyFieldConfig[] = [
{
  key: "select",
  type: "multiselect",
  templateOptions: {
    multiple: false,
    placeholder: "Select Option",
    options: [
      { label: "Select City", value: null },
      { label: "New York", value: { id: 1, name: "New York", code: "NY" } },
      { label: "Rome", value: { id: 2, name: "Rome", code: "RM" } },
      { label: "London", value: { id: 3, name: "London", code: "LDN" } },
      {
        label: "Istanbul",
        value: { id: 4, name: "Istanbul", code: "IST" }
      },
      { label: "Paris", value: { id: 5, name: "Paris", code: "PRS" } }
    ],
      openModal() {
         this.modalRef = this.modalService.show(CalenderComponent,  {
         initialState: {
         title: 'Modal title'
       }
  });
 }, 
 }
}
```

Comment: how do you get the error you mentioned in your stackblitz?

Comment: I click on icon of the multiselect row which is in <i class="pi pi-check" (click)="to.openModal()"></i> and then i get the error,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you debug this, you can see that `this` in the context of your function (`openModal`), is the `field` you defined in the `fields` object, which doesnt have the `modalService` service you injected to the component, to overcome this, you can use a lambda expression:

```
  openModal: () => {
    this.modalRef = this.modalService.show(CalenderComponent, {
      initialState: {
        title: "Modal title"
      }
    });
  }
```

this keeps the closure as you wanted, you can read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures)

After you solve that problem, you will face another one:
[image]

To overcome this, you need to add the `CalenderComponent` as an entrycomponent in your app module file (`app.module.ts`):

```
entryComponents: [CalenderComponent]
```

Here is a forked working [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/modal-issue-this-wasnt-defined-well?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Described in best way, thanks for the support and the solution provided, i got the concept of using closure and the use of entryComponents. Please upVote the question for better reach. Cheers!

Comment: Moshezauros could you help me in one of the requirement : last comment of the answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65284562/disable-dropdown-close-of-multiselect-on-click-of-a-field-inside-multiselect-dro/65298879#65298879